Unir pdf en google Appscript
Estoy desarrollando un script que debe unir varios pdf de una carpeta de un Drive.
Por eso recurri a google AppScript.
Les comparte un avance de codigo con el que estoy trabajando:
function combinePdfs() {
  // IDs de los archivos PDF que deseas combinar
  var pdfIds = ['1Y2MH6Fugn6tXCpLqJ6QfEWVHt8noFzDx', '1XfEgUH7TgEKDT_KRDmcX4YBuw6L4tx2J'];  // Reemplaza con los IDs de tus archivos PDF
  
  // Nombre del archivo combinado
  var combinedPdfName = 'nuevo.pdf';

  // Crear un array de blobs de archivos PDF
  var blobs = [];
  var uno = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfIds[0]);
  var dos = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfIds[1]);

  for (var i = 0; i < pdfIds.length; i++) {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfIds[i]);
    blobs.push(file.getBlob());
  }
  
  // Crear un nuevo archivo PDF en blanco
  var combinedBlob = Utilities.newBlob('', 'application/pdf', combinedPdfName);

  // Combinar los blobs en un solo archivo PDF usando la API de Google Drive
  var combinedFile = Drive.Files.insert(
    {
      title: combinedPdfName,
      mimeType: 'application/pdf'
    },
    combinedBlob
  );
  // Actualizar el archivo PDF combinado con los blobs de los archivos originales
  blobs.forEach((blob =>{
    Drive.Files.update(
      {
        title: 'nuevito',
        mimeType: 'application/pdf'
      },
      combinedFile.id,
      blob
    )
  }))

  Logger.log('Archivo combinado creado con ID: ' + combinedFile.id);
}

Ahora bien, este me genera un pdf nuevo, pero en no une los dos pdf, sino que deja solo uno.
No logro unificar el criterio para que funcione. Tambien intente vincular una libreria externa PDF-lib. Pero el ID que encuentro para ingresar no es valido.

1FGsq1qWLqsC9A7uK-1q4I8kQWcMBmWcdymmsXSAPn8sSvqUq0x1sGo4V

Ya se me escatiman las ideas con este uso de herramienta. Si tienen alguna idea de como encarar esto me seria de gran ayuda.
Desde ya muchas gracias!

Puedes usar la biblioteca PDFApp para ello. Te explico paso por paso lo que tendrías que hacer:

Abrir tu proyecto en el editor de Apps Script.
En el panel de la izquierda, hacer clic en el signo + que aparece delante de Bibliotecas y poner allí la clave de proyecto de la biblioteca antes referida, que aparece en la página del proyecto de Github (enlace al inicio de esta respuesta). Dicha clave es 1Xmtr5XXEakVql7N6FqwdCNdpdijsJOxgqH173JSB0UOwdb0GJYJbnJLk. Y pulsar en el botón Añadir. Si no tienes los permisos adecuados para lo que requiere la biblioteca, te pedirá de otorgar esos permisos. En el apartado Scopes están enumerados los permisos requeridos. Una vez hecho eso, en el panel de la izquierda verás que la biblioteca ha sido agregada bajo el nombre de PDFApp.
Finalmente, puedes implementar el siguiente código, para combinar tus PDFs.


function combinePDF()
{
  /*
    IDs de los archivos a combinar ...
    Pueden ser más de dos 
  */
  const blobA = DriveApp.getFileById("ID_PDF_A").getBlob();
  const blobB = DriveApp.getFileById("ID_PDF_B").getBlob();

  /*
    Creamos un array con los archivos.
    El PDF combinado respeterá el orden en que estén
    los archivos aquí.
  */

  const pdfBlobs = [blobA, blobB];
  
  /*
    La carpeta donde queremos guardar el archivo final.
    Si usamos el código genérico, el archivo
    se creará en la carpeta principal de Drive
  */
  const mergeFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID_FOLDER_DESTINO');

  /*
    El nombre del archivo. 
    Si no ponemos nada, se creará un archivo
    con el nombre newPDFFile.pdf
  */
  var fileName='merged.pdf';

  PDFApp.mergePDFs(pdfBlobs)
    .then(newBlob => mergeFolder.createFile(newBlob))
    .then(newFile => newFile.setName(fileName))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

En la captura de pantalla podrás ver el resultado. En este caso hemos unido dos PDFs, cada uno con una página y simplemente con el texto PDF 1 y PDF 2 en cada archivo respectivo.


Estimado buenos dias!! Muchisimas gracias por su respuesta. Me fue de gran ayuda y de manera muy sencilla.

Estimado buenas tardes. Quisiera consultarle si tiene experiencia en esta biblioteca, conoces alguna forma para manejar los pdf que vienen encriptados? Lei la documentacion en Git pero no encuentro demasiado al respecto.

¿Se refiere a PDFs que vienen protegidos con contraseña? ¿Conoce de antemano la contraseña?

No con contraseña para leer, sino que esta encriptado creo yo que para manipular. Es decir con app como IlovePDF y otras puedo unirlos sin problema pero no asi con PDFapp. Ya que me devuelve el siguiente error. [Error: Input document toPDFDocument.loadis encrypted. You can usePDFDocument.load(..., { ignoreEncryption: true }) if you wish to load the document anyways.]
Ya que estoy manipulando PDF emitidos por entidades publicas como AFIP.  Intente crear una copy del blob, pero la replica sigue manteniendo el encriptado.
Y me es fundamental para mi progreso de desarrollo.
Gracias !

Entiendo. Voy a revisar la doc y el código fuente de la biblioteca para ver si es posible hacerlo. Y, en caso de que no sea posible, ver si hay otra biblioteca que pueda resolverlo.

Bueno, la doc dice que no es compatible para archivos encriptados.

Gracias por la informacion. Entonces seguire buscando alternativas para trabajar con este tipo de documentos. Muchisimas gracias ! e igual como no debo modificar nada, tengo que intentar probar con el
const pdfDoc = PDFDocument.load(encryptedPdfBytes, { ignoreEncryption: true })
SI resuelvo algo lo notificare. Gracias nuevamente!
